# PowerShell command to add character to filename at specific position

Tags: powershell, rename

I'd like to add underscore character "_" at position 22 of a filename.
What would be the PowerShell command to do it?

Comment: Rename-Item can rename files for you.

Comment: Please read the question - I don't want to rename "a" to "b". I want to add underscore at specific position.

Comment: I've read the question. It's not clear what you are having difficulty with. If I wanted to rename a file as requested then I would 1) Get the filename into variable called $before 2) Create another variable with the filename modified as intended in a variable called $after. 3) Call Rename-Item $before $after.           If you are following a similar process to me then you haven't told us what you are having trouble with 1, 2 or 3?       As you ask about renaming and not about creating a string with an underscore in it at a particular position I am assuming it is 3 that you have trouble with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

alternately you can also make use of the string method `insert`

```
Get-Item -Path $Path | 
  Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName.insert(22,'_') + $_.Extension} -WhatIf
```

note: remove `-whatif` to apply the rename

Comment: Thank You. This is exactly what I was asking for. Have a good day, kind sir.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `-replace` and a simple regex to achieve that.

In the following example, I first retrieve the file using the [Get-Item](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113319) cmdlet and rename it using [Rename-Item](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113382):

```
Get-Item $YOURPATH | % { $_ | Rename-Item -NewName ($_.Name -replace '^([\S\s]{22})', '$1_')}
```

You may have to add a check whether the file name is long enough, otherwise it could happen, that you rename the file extension or nothing...

Comment: This one does not add underscore, it replaces any character at position 22 with the underscore character.

Answer (score 0):

below script will add '-' at position 3 and 6 and 9 and 12 and 15

**from: s270120070336.bmp**

**to: s27-01-20-07-03-36.bmp**

Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\users\sonook\desktop\screenshot' -Filter '*.bmp' |

```
ForEach-Object { $_ | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName.insert(3,'-').insert(6,'-').insert(9,'-').insert(12,'-').insert(15,'-') + $_.Extension}}
```